# How do I combine and aggregate Data Frame rows

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which looks somewhat like this:

```
endPoint    power    time
device1      -4       0
device2       3       0
device3      -2       0
device4       0       0
device5       5       0
device6      -5       0
device1       4       1
device2      -3       1
device3       5       1
device4      -2       1
device5       1       1
device6       4       1
....
device1       6       x
device2      -5       x
device3       4       x
device4       3       x
device5      -1       x
device6       1       x
```

I want to change it into something like this:

```
span               powerAboveThreshold    time
device1-device3        true                 0
device2-device6        true                 0
...
devicex-devicey        false                w
```

I want to aggregate rows into two new columns and group this by time and span. The value of `powerAboveThreshold` depends on whether or not the `power` for either device in the span is above 0 - so if `devicex` or `devicey` is below 0 then it will be false.

As a side-note, there is one span of devices which contains 4 devices - whereas the rest contain just 2 devices. I need to design with this in mind.

`device1-device3-device6-device2`

I am using the Apache Spark DataFrame API/Spark SQL to accomplish this.

edit:

Could I convert the DataFrame to an RDD and compute it that way?

edit2:

Follow-up questions to Daniel L:

Seems like a great answer from what I have understood so far. I have a few questions:

- Will the RDD have the expected structure if I convert it from a DataFrame?
- What is going on in this part of the program? `.aggregateByKey(Result())((result, sample) => aggregateSample(result, sample), addResults)`. I see that it runs `aggregateSample()` with each key-value pair (result, sample), but how does the `addResults` call work? Will it be called on each item relating to a key to add each successive Result generated by `aggregateSample` to the previous ones? I don't fully understand.
- What is `.map(_._2)` doing?
- In what situation will `result.span` be empty in the `aggregateSample` function?
- In what situation will `res1.span` be empty in the `addResults` function?

Sorry for all of the questions, but I'm new to functional programming, Scala, and Spark so I have a lot to wrap my head around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do the text concatenation as you want on DataFrames (maybe you can), but on a normal RDD you can  do this:

```
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(Seq(
  ("device1", -4, 0),
  ("device2", 3, 0),
  ("device3", -2, 0),
  ("device4", 0, 0),
  ("device5", 5, 0),
  ("device6", -5, 0),
  ("device1", 4, 1),
  ("device2", -3, 1),
  ("device3", 5, 1),
  ("device4", 1, 1),
  ("device5", 1, 1),
  ("device6", 4, 1)))

val spanMap = Map(
"device1" -> 1,
"device2" -> 1,
"device3" -> 1,
"device4" -> 2,
"device5" -> 2,
"device6" -> 1
)

case class Result(var span: String = "", var aboveThreshold: Boolean = true, var time: Int = -1)
def aggregateSample(result: Result, sample: (String, Int, Int)) = {
  result.time = sample._3
  result.aboveThreshold = result.aboveThreshold && (sample._2 > 0)
  if(result.span.isEmpty)
    result.span += sample._1
  else
    result.span += "-" + sample._1
  result
}
def addResults(res1: Result, res2: Result) = {
  res1.aboveThreshold = res1.aboveThreshold && res2.aboveThreshold
  if(res1.span.isEmpty)
    res1.span += res2.span
  else
    res1.span += "-" + res2.span
  res1
}

val results = rdd
  .map(x => (x._3, spanMap.getOrElse(x._1, 0)) -> x)  // Create a key to agregate with, by time and span
  .aggregateByKey(Result())((result, sample) => aggregateSample(result, sample), addResults)
  .map(_._2)

results.collect().foreach(println(_))
```

And it prints this, which is what I understood you needed:

```
Result(device4-device5,false,0)
Result(device4-device5,true,1)
Result(device1-device2-device3-device6,false,0)
Result(device1-device2-device3-device6,false,1)
```

Here I use a map that tells me which devices go together (for your pairings and 4-device exception), you might want to replace it with some other function, hardcode it as a static function to avoid serialization or use a broadcast variable.

=================== Edit ==========================

> Seems like a great answer from what I have understood so far.

Feel free to upvote/accept it, helps me an others looking for things to answer :-)

> Will the RDD have the expected structure if I convert it from a DataFrame?

Yes, the main difference is that a DataFrame includes a schema, so it can better optimize the underling calls, should be trivial to use this schema directly or map to the tuples I used as an example, I did it mostly for convenience. Hernan just posted another answer that shows some of this (and also copied the initial test data I used for convenience), so I won't repeat that piece, but as he mentions, your device-span grouping and presentation is tricky and thus I preferred a more imperative way on an RDD.

> What is going on in this part of the program? .aggregateByKey(Result())((result, sample) => aggregateSample(result, sample), addResults). I see that it runs aggregateSample() with each key-value pair (result, sample), but how does the addResults call work? Will it be called on each item relating to a key to add each successive Result generated by aggregateSample to the previous ones? I don't fully understand.

`aggregateByKey` is a very optimal function. To avoid shuffling all data from one node to another to later merge, it first does local aggregation of samples to a single result per key, locally (the first function). They it shuffles these results around and adds the up (the second function).

> What is .map(_._2) doing?

Simply discarding the key from the key/value RDD after aggregation, you no longer care about it, so I just keep the result.

> In what situation will result.span be empty in the aggregateSample function?
>   In what situation will res1.span be empty in the addResults function?

When you do aggregation, you need to provide a "zero" value. For instance, if you where aggregating numbers, Spark would do (0 + firstValue) + secondValue... etc. The if clause prevent the adding of a spurious '-' before the first device name, since we put it between devices. No different than dealing for instance with one extra comma on a list of items, etc. Check the documentation and samples for `aggregateByKey`, it will help you a lot.

Comment: Seems like a great answer from what I can understand (which is most of it). I've added a few follow-up questions to the OP, if you're willing to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

This is the implementation for dataframes (without the concated names):

```
val data = Seq(
  ("device1", -4, 0),
  ("device2", 3, 0),
  ("device3", -2, 0),
  ("device4", 0, 0),
  ("device5", 5, 0),
  ("device6", -5, 0),
  ("device1", 4, 1),
  ("device2", -3, 1),
  ("device3", 5, 1),
  ("device4", 1, 1),
  ("device5", 1, 1),
  ("device6", 4, 1)).toDF("endPoint", "power", "time")

val mapping = Seq(
  "device1" -> 1,
  "device2" -> 1,
  "device3" -> 1,
  "device4" -> 2,
  "device5" -> 2,
  "device6" -> 1).toDF("endPoint", "span")

data.as("A").
  join(mapping.as("B"), $"B.endpoint" === $"A.endpoint", "inner").
  groupBy($"B.span", $"A.time").
  agg(min($"A.power" > 0).as("powerAboveThreshold")).
  show()
```

Concated names are quite a bit harder, this requires you either to write your own UDAF (supported in the next version of Spark), or to use a combination of Hive functions.

Comment: Cheers. Could I map the devices to a string - say "Span 1" - instead of an int, in order to produce a more readable output? It's almost as good as concatenating the names.

Comment: You can, integers are just faster/simpler to hash/compare. Buy any unique key will do.

Comment: Great. Last question: what do I need to import for Seq().toDF() to work? It works fine in the spark-shell, but it doesn't work in my code. Supposedly `toDF()` is not a member of Seq.

Comment: `toDF()` can be enabled by importing `sqlContext.implicits._`.